# How to retrieve MS WORD(2003) doc file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, docx

I'm doing a project which is related on analytic. For that i need to count some row's values from MS WORD. If it is .docx extension then there is no problem for me but when it is a .doc extension, I cannot suppose to read those files. What can i do for that? I'm using python 3.6 and installed .docx module as well. Expecting a good answer. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using win32com:

```
import win32com

from win32com.client import gencache, constants, Dispatch
# that's the magic part
gencache.EnsureModule('{00020905-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}', 0, 8, 3)

app = Dispatch("Word.Application.8")
# open a document
app.Documents.Open("MyDocument.doc")
```

Now you can do whatever you want with this document.
If the line with gencache gives you an error then  you will need to create the COM module first by executing:

```
lib\site-packages\win32com\client\makepy.py
```

This will pop-up a Window where you need to select the 'Microsoft Word Object Library'.